# I'm having a horizontal problem in stackpanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set the vertical setting of a button to the bottom in the stackpanel, but it doesn't.

I have read a few topics but I have not been successful. Is there anything I can use other than stackpanel ?

I want to push down the last button.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="#312a28">
    <!--Left panel buttons-->
    <StackPanel>
        <!--Button icon list-->
            <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
                <Image Source="img/icon_list.png" Height="50" Width="50"/>
            </Button>
            <!--Button new order-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/ordertake_neworder.png" Height="35" Width="34" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Yeni" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <!--Button order-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/orders_icon_white.png" Height="40" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Sipariş" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <!--Button payment-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/icon_payment.png" Height="40" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Ödeme" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <!--Button Sales-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/hot_sales_icon.png" Height="40" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Satış" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <!--Button printer-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/payment_printer.png" Height="40" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Yazdır" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <!--Button back-->
      (This Button) -->  <Button Height="70" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/previous.png" Height="40" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. Which Button are you talking about? A StackPanel arranges its child elements from top to bottom (or left to right).

Comment: @Clemens out of sight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `DockPanel` with `LastChildFill="False"`. Put `DockPanel.Dock="Top"` on every Button but the last one. Give the last Button `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`.

Answer (score 1):

To push down the last button to the very end, you could use a DockPanel for this:
With using the standard DockPanel.LastChildFill option (true), the stackpanel will fill everything up until the Button up top.

```
<DockPanel >
    <!--Button back-->
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
            Height="70" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <StackPanel Width="70">
            <Image Source="img/previous.png" Height="40" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <StackPanel>
        <!--Button icon list-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <Image Source="img/icon_list.png" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        </Button>
        <!--Button new order-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/ordertake_neworder.png" Height="35" Width="34" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Yeni" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <!--Button order-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/orders_icon_white.png" Height="40" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Sipariş" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <!--Button payment-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/icon_payment.png" Height="40" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Ödeme" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <!--Button Sales-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/hot_sales_icon.png" Height="40" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Satış" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <!--Button printer-->
        <Button Height="70" Background="#556ac1">
            <StackPanel Width="70">
                <Image Source="img/payment_printer.png" Height="40" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Yazdır" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```